# Using QHash in a custom class

Tags: c++, qt

I am newbie in Qt and learning to handle how QHash works. On working with this example I dont understand why this throws me an error. I may miss something, but please guide me to learn this.

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QHash<QString,Person> hash;
QString key="1";

Person p;
p.name = name;
p.number = an;

hash.insert(key,p); 

    return a.exec();
}
```

person.h

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    Person(QString name,QString num);
    bool operator==(const Person & other) const; //== overloading to assign in QHash
    QString name,number;
};
```

person.cpp

```
Person::Person()
{
}
Person::Person(QString name, QString num)
{
    this->name=name;
    this->number=num;
}
bool Person::operator==(const Person & other) const
{
    bool state;
    if (name == other.name )
        state = true;
    else
        state = false;

    return state;
}
```

and the error is:-'qHash':none of the 17 overloads could convert all the argument type.I knw im missing something.Please guide me.

Comment: which compiler and QT version are you using? This compiles fine to me.

Comment: For custom types a keys, you need to provide a qHash function for that type. As you're using QString, you should be fine though.

Comment: i'm using qt creator 2.7

Comment: Also, what are "name" and "an" in the assignments in main? They are not defined anywhere.

Comment: FWIW, your `Person::operator==` could be written as just `return (name == other.name)` and would be a good candidate for inlining, but perhaps you've just cut it down for this example.

Comment: those r QString local variable assignin to my members of person class

Comment: yeah tats a good one tristan but my pblm is its nt compiling wen im using hash to my custom class

Comment: Have you included QString and QHash?

Comment: OFFTOPIC: You could implement only Person(QString name=QString::null, QString num=QString::null). A default constructor is one, that can be called **without** parameters (not necessarily one having **no** parameters). I assume, you implemented Person() only for using the class in container.

Comment: @valentin Yeah i knw that it was nt necessary my pblm is different n i got it solved.............

Comment: The question and the accepted answer simply don't match, and I doubt you got the error trying to compile **this** code. -1 (at least until straightening things out).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the global `qHash()` function.

> A QHash's key type has additional requirements other than being an
>   assignable data type: it must provide operator==(), and there must
>   also be a qHash() function in the type's namespace that returns a hash
>   value for an argument of the key's type.

See [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qhash.html#qhash) for more info about that.

Comment: @peppe Oh yeah. I didn't notice that. That is strange. Why would this solve his problem..

Comment: @anbuselvan Actually your code seems fine. Did you leave some of your code out?

Comment: @thuga no the prblm was qHash() was not global it was inside my person class

Comment: -1: Answering without reading the question? The problem here is not the hash-key but not compilable example. Sorry for down-voting :-(

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz It's OK. I paid attention to the error message and the fact that he has defined the `operator==()`, and I didn't notice that he was using `QString` as the key in his hash-table. But it turns out he is actually using `Person` as the key so my answer is indeed correct.

Comment: Although the answer is correct, it doesn't actually answer the question (as it is now).

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided is not complete and not compilable - e.g. The symbol name is not found, no includes.

The op == is not required when you use the class as value. The only one requirement for value-classes - a default constructor.

I think you problem was something else. If you provided the complete code and the complete list of errors I could tell you what exactly.

Below you'll find the working version of you code-snippet. (For simplicity, everything in one file)

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHash>
#include <QString>

class Person
{
public:
    Person(QString name=QString::null,QString num=QString::null);
    QString name,number;
};


Person::Person(QString _name, QString _num)
:name(_name),number(_num)
{   
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QHash<QString,Person> hash;
    QString key="1";

    Person p("Orhan Kemal", "1914");

    hash.insert(key,p); 
        return a.exec();
}
```

Regards,
Valentin

**EDIT:**
Initialized members not in body

Comment: i thnk u didnt get my question i tried to set the key like this:-                                             QHash<Person,QString> hash;                              hash.insert(p,key);                                               and this will obiviously throw error to overload == and i did and got error coz i forgot to implement qHash() function and finally after implementin it in right place  got it solved

Comment: The mathematical lows seems to be universal: minus * minus = plus. You've provided wrong example. Someone didn't read the question carefully and answered. By chance, this answer was right (or what you consider as right for your problem). :-)

Comment: i dont get you mate what is wrong in taking the key as object do they cross the law of oops @valentin