# How to override qHash() function?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'd like to use a `QSet` of customized object. From the documentation, I found out that:

> QSet's value data type must be an assignable data type. You cannot, for example, store a QWidget as a value; instead, store a QWidget *. In addition, the type must provide operator==(), and there must also be a global qHash() function that returns a hash value for an argument of the key's type. See the QHash documentation for a list of types supported by qHash().

The following code represents the `struct` I'd like to use:

```
typedef struct ShortcutItem
{
    QString     shortcutName;   // A shortcut name
    QString     explaination;   // A shortcut explaination
    bool        editable;       // Is editable
    KeySequence sequence;       // A list of key values defining a shortcut

    ShortcutItem(void) {}
    ShortcutItem(QString& name, QString& description, bool enabled, KeySequence seq) : shortcutName(name), explaination(description), editable(enabled), sequence(seq) {}
    ShortcutItem(const ShortcutItem& other) : shortcutName(other.shortcutName), explaination(other.explaination), editable(other.editable), sequence(other.sequence) {}
    bool ShortcutItem::operator==(const ShortcutItem& other) const { return shortcutName == other.shortcutName; }
} ShortcutItem;
```

Till now, I've overloaded `==` operator, but can't determine what to do with `qHash()` function.

Any help, please.

P.S. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805207/using-qhash-in-a-custom-class) and can't decide what to do.

Comment: Just overload `qHash` in the normal way (i.e. `uint qHash(const ShortcutItem&, uint seed = 0);`).

Comment: Only add this line as it is: `uint qHash(const ShortcutItem&, uint seed = 0);` ?

Comment: You'll obviously need to implement that function as well as declaring!

Comment: @TobySpeight This is my question :)
I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see from your code, your hashing function should look like

```
uint qHash(const ShortcutItem & item)
{
    return qHash(item.shortcutName);
}
```

In other words, you can employ the available overload `uint qHash(const QString &key, uint seed = ...)`, pass the item member `shortcutName` to it, and just return its return value.

You can put the function prototype after the `ShortcutItem` struct, in its very header:

```
uint qHash(const ShortcutItem & item);
```

and the definition (above) in its implementation file (.cpp).

Comment: Is that acceptable?
`static uint qHash(const ShortcutItem & item)
{
    return qHash(item.shortcutName);
}`

Comment: No need to be `static`. Just put it after the struct (it isn't a struct member, just a function on its own).

Comment: When I remove `static`, it gives me this error: "..\..\lib\certifixwidgetsd1.dll:-1: error: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found"

Comment: I'm so sorry if I got you annoyed, but I don't have an implementation file. It's only a header file.

Comment: @MohammedDeifallah You don't have an implementation file? Time to have one ;)